# Graph API 2.3 Event location

Tags: api, events, location

If I query an api request for the location of an event I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#12) location field is deprecated for versions v2.3 and higher", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 12
  }
}
```

I'm making a party calender based on facebook events. without the location the app is useless.. Is there any way around?

Comment: Same issue for interest I change the version 2.3 to 2.2 its working but I have to do in android.

Answer (score 1):

You should use place as specified here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/event :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{event-id}/?fields=place
```

Comment: Than I get 

{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unknown path components: /place", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 2500
  }
}

Comment: I have forgotten the ?fields= in the Graph API Query. I've just try with this 329097513961022?fields=place and it works.